# Do not auto-connect to Wifi connection in Android 7.0

Tags: wi-fi, 7.0-nougat

I have a Moto G4 phone running Android 7.0. There are multiple Wifi connections in my workplace, and I want to default to the private Wifi network, while having the building's Wifi as a backup.

[image: Wifi connection]

In the Wifi connection's settings, I do not see an option for **Do not connect automatically**.

As far as I know on Xiaomi and Samsumg phones, there is an option not to connect to a Wifi network automatically. How can I achieve the same result with a Moto G4 / stock Android 7.0 phone?

Comment: On my system (Android 9, Sony) the auto-connect settings are not located in the entry of the saved Wifi itself, but in the general Wifi settings -> Extended settings -> Autoconnect. There I can enable or disable autoconnect for each saved Wifi.

Comment: @Robert AFAIK, on Android 7 (Nexus, LineageOS), there's no "Autoconnect" settings. There's "Saved Networks" behind the cog wheel icon, but there's no other options other than forgetting the network from there.

Comment: See if answered addressed here work: [How to prevent Wifi auto-connect without forgetting that connection](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/131116/209414)